# .NET Core MVC - DropDownList from Enumerable produces an "multiple" - How to remove?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Site with a Row "Employees", which has eight Dropdowns. To these Dropdowns I have bound a ViewBag with all the Employees and the same List Property.
THe problem with this is that it will produce an "multiple" HTML output, where I can select multiple Employees and the whole Dropdown is showing as a List.

Basically:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
      <select asp-for="Employees" asp-items="ViewBag.Employees" class="form-control" >       </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm">
      <select asp-for="Employees" asp-items="ViewBag.Employees" class="form-control">       </select>
   .......
```

In the Model:

```
public ICollection<int?>? Employees { get; set; }
```

When I run this Page: 1.) The Dropdown will be "multiple select" and 2.) The Dropdown is shown like a List. It shows all the Employees openly without clicking on it.

Can I somehow prevent this without declaring eight "Employee 1-8" Properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your type is `ICollection<int?>?`, So `asp-for` will generate `multiple="multiple"` property, You just need to use `name="Employees"` instead of `asp-for="Employees"` in this case.

Code:

```
<div class="col-sm">
     <select asp-for="Employees" asp-items="ViewBag.Employees" class="form-control">       </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
     <select name="Employees" asp-items="ViewBag.Employees" class="form-control">       </select>
</div>
```

View:

[image]